# Using regex to find key/values from a javascript function return statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not quite sure how to explain this in short, so the title might be a tad confusing...

I have this piece of javascript code *string*: (which is stripped clean from line-breaks, double white spaces, etc.):

```
function (a, b) { this.super('__construct', a, b); return { foo: this.test, bar: this.ParentFunctionAdd }; }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get an array of keys/values from the return statement of this function. Executing the code or using eval isn't an option.

So essentially, I want to match anything between the curly-braces of the return statement and get a key/value array in return.

The desired result would be the following:

```
{
    'foo' : 'this.test',
    'bar' : 'this.ParentFunctionAdd'
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you assume that there will not be child objects of the object you want?

Comment: @PaulS. Well, no. But that'll be the next "challenge". For now, this is enough :)

If the return statement refrences to a variable which is essentially the object that I need to pare, I could use the same regex with a slight modification.

Comment: You can use http://esprima.org for example.

Comment: Can the values be arbitrary expressions, or are they always `this.propertyname`?

Comment: Barmar, it would be valid for them to be anything. But the 'convention' for my project would be a reference to a method inside the prototype, yeah.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh wow! That's awesome. Although a little large for a dependency. If this can't be solved with some regex-magic, I'll definitely look into that. Cheers!

Comment: @Harold: *Paul S.: "Can you assume that there will not be child objects of the object you want?" Harold: "Well, no. But that'll be the next 'challenge'."* No, it won't. It means that even if you come up with a regex solution for the above, you *cannot* use it for your next challenge. In fact, the problem becomes something that you cannot purely use regex for, you need a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer doing it with regex, here's a solution

```
/([^{,]+):([^},]+)/g
```

---

```
"function (a, b) { this.super('__construct', a, b); return { foo: this.test, bar: this.ParentFunctionAdd }; }".match(/([^{,]+):([^},]+)/g);
```

This is the output

```
[" foo: this.test", " bar: this.ParentFunctionAdd "]
```

As you can see, you need to trim() values when use them.

Check [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nF6mT1/1)

Comment: That perfectly suits my needs! Also a lot simpeler than I thought it would be, hehe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Harold: So long as you understand the limits of the solution. For instance, it fails on `function (a, b) { this.super('__construct', a, b); return { foo: {ka: "boom"}, bar: this.ParentFunctionAdd }; }` (http://regex101.com/r/nF6mT1/2) and `function (a, b) { this.super('__construct', a, b); return { foo: "bo{}om", bar: this.ParentFunctionAdd }; }` (http://regex101.com/r/nF6mT1/3). (Nothing against hex's working within the scope, just highlighting the limits.)